# ADO Recordset Type for Date

Tags: sql-server, types, asp-classic, adodb, recordset

Warning:  Classic ASP Ahead.  :)

I'm working on a legacy Classic ASP application and I'm running into an oddity with an ADODB.Recordset object.

I have a SQL2012 database table containing a particular field.  Let's call it **AnnoyingField**.  Its datatype in SQL is 'date'.

The ASP opens an ADODB.Recordset with a SELECT on the table to collect the fields, then does some looping to do its work:

```
For each Field in rs.Fields
    typeid = rs(Field.Name).Type
    'do stuff based on type
```

For some reason, the Type for **AnnoyingField** is coming back as 202 (nvarchar) rather than one of the expected types for date (133 or even 7).  This is causing some issues further in the code.

I tested with another field of 'datetime' type and the Recordset code returned the expected Type for a datetime field.. 135.

Anyone have an idea why the 'date' fields are returning as an nvarchar?

Changing the database fields from date to datetime in this case might not be possible, even though it might be the logical path to take to get expected data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date fields are newer than your version of ADODB. So it doesn't understand what it's getting.

You may be able to cheer it up by using

```
 select convert(datetime, AnnoyingField) from CrazyFuturisticTable
```

You may also get the correct result if you upgrade your ADODB version to 2.8 and/or connect using the SQL Native Client. Obviously, I haven't tried this, because I live in 2014.

Comment: I agree with @podiluska.  I might even make a view to wrap that table (and convert Annoying field).

Comment: The ADODB.Connection's .Version property reports 6.1, but I think you're still right.  This morning, I found a chart of ADODB types correlated to SQL datatypes and there was no SQL equivalent of 7 or 133, just 135.  So in the end I'm going to have to bite the bullet and change the datatypes somewhere along the way.

Comment: @imukai Wasn't by any chance this? [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx), use it all the time.

Comment: @imukai You should be using `Provider=SQLNCLI10` to support the `DATE` data type (as podiluska points out) as it was only introduced in SQL Server 2008 and above.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep it a little simpler, cut ADO out of the picture and use isdate and "convert date" and vartype.

```
For each Field in rs.Fields
    Field=rs(Field.Name)
    if isdate(Field) then Field=cdate(Field)  ' just in case
    typeid = VarType(Field)
    'do stuff based on type
```

Vartype 
http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_vartype.asp

ADO .type can report more "types"
http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_para_type.asp

But I think what vartype can offer should help people in 95% of cases.

Word of warning with cdate, depending on what the server locale is set too or your Session.LCID (in your code) is set will determine what format the date will be formatted to. Shouldn't be a problem for most people but obviously test to see if you get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  This would work if the "do stuff" were all read-only, but there is an update portion of code that modifies the recordset then saves it via .update.  In the case of setting a date field to = '' you end up getting the default date (1900?) which is how the issue was noticed in the first place.  I'm going to have to convert them to datetime first so the code feeds it back a date or NULL rather than an empty string before the update.

Comment: You should have put that information in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Classic ASP / VBScript and have found that for SQL2012 using SQL Native driver ("Provider=SQLNCLI11"), and the ADO module provided by Windows (presumably Vista or newer [mine is Windows Servr2012 R2 - the version [MyDbConn.version] shows as 6.3) this now works again.

I had been looking for / expecting the Field.Type to be adDate [7], but am actually getting adDBDate [133]